# Nested XML to dataframe with BeautifulSoup or Elementtree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML file which reperesents transactions of products. I would like to transform this data in to a pandas dataframe but don't know how iterate the  to get all product level data.

Here's an XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<order-root>
    <order ordernumber="12345">
        <orderheader>
            <customerid>114597</customerid>
            <paymentmethod>333</paymentmethod>
            <shippingmethod>127</shippingmethod>
            <orderdatum>2020-01-01 00:47:42</orderdatum>
            <orderstatus>6</orderstatus>
            <currency>Dollar</currency>
        </orderheader>
        <orderrows>
            <orderrow orderrownumber="1">
                <articlenumber>10004171</articlenumber>
                <articlename>Random name 1</articlename>
                <unit>1</unit>
                <price>2543</price>
                <vat>25</vat>
            </orderrow>
        </orderrows>
    </order>
    <order ordernumber="23456">
        <orderheader>
            <customerid>114602</customerid>
            <paymentmethod>333</paymentmethod>
            <shippingmethod>109</shippingmethod>
            <orderdatum>2020-01-01 10:45:45</orderdatum>
            <orderstatus>6</orderstatus>
            <currency>Dollar</currency>
        </orderheader>
        <orderrows>
            <orderrow orderrownumber="1">
                <articlenumber>10448306</articlenumber>
                <articlename>Random name 2</articlename>
                <unit>1</unit>
                <price>235</price>
                <vat>25</vat>
            </orderrow>
            <orderrow orderrownumber="2">
                <articlenumber>10448272</articlenumber>
                <articlename>Random name 3</articlename>
                <unit>1</unit>
                <price>109</price>
                <vat>25</vat>
            </orderrow>
        </orderrows>
    </order>
        <order ordernumber="34567">
        <orderheader>
            <customerid>114327</customerid>
            <paymentmethod>333</paymentmethod>
            <shippingmethod>109</shippingmethod>
            <orderdatum>2020-01-01 10:45:45</orderdatum>
            <orderstatus>6</orderstatus>
            <currency>Dollar</currency>
        </orderheader>
        <orderrows>
            <orderrow orderrownumber="1">
                <articlenumber>10448306</articlenumber>
                <articlename>Random name 2</articlename>
                <unit>1</unit>
                <price>235</price>
                <vat>25</vat>
            </orderrow>
            <orderrow orderrownumber="2">
                <articlenumber>10448272</articlenumber>
                <articlename>Random name 3</articlename>
                <unit>1</unit>
                <price>109</price>
                <vat>25</vat>
            </orderrow>
            <orderrow orderrownumber="3">
                <articlenumber>10448562</articlenumber>
                <articlename>Random name 4</articlename>
                <unit>1</unit>
                <price>23</price>
                <vat>25</vat>
            </orderrow>
        </orderrows>
    </order>
</order-root>
```

And this is what i expect as the final result:

| ordernumber | customerid | paymentmethod | shippingmethod | orderdatum | orderstatus | currency | orderrownumber | articlenumber | articlename | unit | price | vat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 114597 | 333 | 127 | 2020-01-01 0:47:42 | 6 | Dollar | 1 | 10004171 | Random name 1 | 1 | 2543 | 25 |
| 23456 | 114602 | 333 | 109 | 2020-01-01 10:45:45 | 6 | Dollar | 1 | 10448306 | Random name 2 | 1 | 235 | 25 |
| 23456 | 114602 | 333 | 109 | 2020-01-02 10:45:45 | 6 | Dollar | 2 | 10448272 | Random name 3 | 1 | 109 | 25 |
| 34567 | 114327 | 333 | 109 | 2020-01-01 10:45:45 | 6 | Dollar | 1 | 10448306 | Random name 2 | 1 | 235 | 25 |
| 34567 | 114327 | 333 | 109 | 2020-01-02 10:45:45 | 6 | Dollar | 2 | 10448272 | Random name 3 | 1 | 109 | 25 |
| 34567 | 114327 | 333 | 109 | 2020-01-03 10:45:45 | 6 | Dollar | 3 | 10448562 | Random name 4 | 1 | 23 | 25 |

Comment: Please (re)read [ask] and edit your question with your attempt in the form of a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the question of how to iterate the data, you can go through with **XPath** and use "*" to select all children of a WebElement:
import os
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

```
html_Input = open("path of html", "r")
tree = ET.parse(html_Input)
root = tree.getroot()

for order in root.findall("/order-root/order"):
    for child in order.findall("./orderheader/*"):
        print(f"{child}\n")
    for child in order.findall("./orderrows/*"):
        print(f"{child}\n")

html_Input.close()
```

Referring to creating a pandas dataframe from an XML, pandas already has an option with **read_xml**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_xml("Your XML file", xpath=".//order") #Each order WebElement contains all data for each row.
df
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I needed to solve the issue:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_xml("Your XML file", xpath=".//order") #Each order WebElement contains all data for each row.
df
```

Comment: What does this answer help? Have you tried to print it?